How can I add a border bottom to Vuetify v-tabs?
I'd like to achieve following result:

I did it by doing this
<v-tabs>
  <v-tab
    v-for="(tab, i) in tabs"
    :key="i"
    v-bind="tab"
  ></v-tab>
</v-tabs>
<v-divider></v-divider>

But I don't want to use the <v-divider>, I'd like to get the same appearance through CSS. I tried this
<template>
  <v-tabs class="bordered-tab">
    <v-tab
      v-for="(tab, i) in tabs"
      :key="i"
      v-bind="tab"
    ></v-tab>
  </v-tabs>
</template>

<style scoped>
.bordered-tab {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
</style>

And this is the result

The blue border should be on top of the red one. How can I do it?
Edit #1
Thanks to @kissu insights, I was able to achieve my goal. This is the full code:
<template>
  <v-tabs class="bordered-tabs">
    <v-tab
      v-for="(tab, i) in tabs"
      :key="i"
      v-bind="tab"
    ></v-tab>
  </v-tabs>
</template>

<style scoped>
.bordered-tabs >>> .v-slide-group__content {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0000001e;
}
</style>

The other thing I'd like to do is to apply this style to all the .v-slide-group__content without having to explicitly add a class to them, something like:
.v-slide-group__content {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0000001e;
}

How can I do it?
Edit #2
Since I wanted to apply above class to horizontal <v-tabs> only, I wrote following rule in my main.css
.v-tabs:not(.v-tabs--vertical) .v-slide-group__content {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0000001e;
}

With this rule
<!-- border-bottom will be applied -->
<v-tabs>
  <!-- tabs... -->
</v-tab>

<!-- border-bottom will not be applied -->
<v-tabs direction="vertical">
  <!-- tabs... -->
</v-tabs>


Did you try z-index?

@Wimanicesir yes, no luck.

Yeah without a small example what happens, we can only guess..

@Wimanicesir if you are still interested, kissu solution was spot on.

You can use the following
<style scoped>
  .edit-those-classes >>> .v-slide-group__content {
    border-bottom: 10px orange solid;
  }
</style>

Here is a complete reproduction.
More context about the deep selectors.

If you want to have this behavior globally, you can have a simpler version by removing scoped
<style>
  .v-slide-group__content {
    border-bottom: 10px orange solid;
  }
</style>

